# guzzle read value from response

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle with Laravel to get an object from external API with a HTTP. The API return XML Object similar to this (https://www.w3schools.com/php/note.xml)

I need to check one value of the response body. Here is my code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();    
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.w3schools.com/php/note.xml');    
$stringBody = (string) $res->getBody()->getContents();
echo $stringBody;
```

which is working fine, I mean it display the body as below picture 
[image]

but I couldn't get one value? 
I tried different methods but non of them is working! 
for example, this way:

```
$result = starts_with($stringBody, 'Tove');
```

or

```
splitName = explode(' ', $res->getBody()); 
$first_name = $splitName[0];
echo $first_name;
```

non is working? I think it consider the body text empty ?

I tried using json_decode but it doesn't work or not supported anymore.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Try outputting `$stringBody` using `dd($stringBody)`. This way you can see the exact value of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get from response is xml content. Due to browser compatibility with XML you see only text. You just need SimpleXML class of php for get content as per XML node. Here is sample code

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.w3schools.com/php/note.xml');
    $stringBody = (string) $res->getBody()->getContents();
    $xml =  simplexml_load_string($stringBody);
    echo $xml->to;
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for :)